# Spring Autowire Without Setter Method

Tags: java, spring

I am new to spring. I am attempting to autowire TestDAO without setter method. But i failed to autowire.

System.out.println("TestClass.testDAO "+testDAO); It returns null.

Kindly help me to unlock.

My xml config :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test" />
<context:annotation-config/>

<bean id="testClass" class="com.test.TestClass" autowire="byName">
</bean>
```

Java classes :

```
@Component
public class TestClass {

    @Autowired(required=true)
    public TestDAO testDAO = null;
    {
        System.out.println("TestClass.testDAO "+testDAO);
    }
}

@Repository
public class TestDAO{
}
```

Comment: Of course it will return `null` at that point. The initializer is part of the constructor, spring can only inject dependencies AFTER the constructor has constructed the object. So yes at that point it still is `null` because it will be injected after that.

Comment: Thanks Deinum. I cannot get idea.. Can you please help to correct my code.. Really i am struggling.

Comment: How can spring inject something into an object that doesn't exist? How do you do that? As stated the initializer block the part between `{ }` is copied to the constructor... At that point it still is null... As stated injection happens AFTER that you cannot use `@Autowired` fields in a constructor.

Comment: add class with main method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example about how to fix your code:

```
@Component
public class TestClass {

  @Autowired(required=true)
  public TestDAO testDAO;

  // When someone calls this method, the testDao component should 
  // be initialized with TestDAO instance.
  public void someMethod(){
    System.out.println("TestClass.testDAO "+testDAO);
  }
} 

public interface TestDAO extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long>{
}
```

Also, you could use the `@Autowired` annotation in a constructor.

```
@Component
public class TestClass {

  public TestDAO testDAO;

  @Autowired
  public TestClass(TestDAO testDAO){
   this.testDAO = testDAO;
   System.out.println("TestClass.testDAO "+testDAO);
  }
}
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Did you able to solve your problem with this solution?

Comment: Yes jcgarcia.. Thanks for your help .

Comment: Glad to hear that! :)

Comment: Thanks once again jcgarcia.